# Find greatest non-present value in a DB table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB table (tbl). It has one column - a primary key that is a positive integer (id).
How can I find the greatest value that is not present in the table and is also less than a given value N?

Here is my best shot so far:

```
SELECT MAX(tbl1.id)-1
FROM tbl AS tbl1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM tbl AS tbl2
                  WHERE tbl2.id = (tbl1.id - 1)
                 ) AND
      tbl1.id <= N
```

But this works only when either N or N-1 is present in the table.
If neither is present then I'd like to have N-1 as a result. The query above either returns nothing (if there are no values < N), or something less than N-1 (if there is at least one value < N).

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum value below the largest value in the table, you can use:

```
select max(id) - 1
from (select t.*, lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id
      from tbl t
     ) t
where prev_id <> id - 1
```

To take `N` into account gets tricky, but this should work:

```
select max(case when id < N then id - 1
                when prev_id < N - 1 then N - 1
           end)
from (select t.*, lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id
      from tbl t
     ) t
where prev_id <> id - 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't work if N is less the lowest id. Also, it traverses the whole table which will be very slow when the table starts to fill.
But thank you for showing me LAG and CASE - I saw them for the first time.

Comment: @Gbr . . . If N is less than the lowest id, then this works -- it returns `NULL`.

Comment: @Gbr . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the missing rows from two lists, you can use "Left Join Same table Where SecondTable.PK is null"
in your example the Left Join condition would be id +1 = id.

```
select max(T1.id)
from tbl T1
    left Join tbl T2
        on T1.id +1= T2.id 
where T1.id between 1 and 2000      /*Specify your range*/ 
    AND T2.id  is null
```